# filter results from subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

For the following query:

```
SELECT t_stamp, sum(t_diff) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp) AS t_sum
FROM (
    SELECT
        t_stamp
        , getdiffabove(t_stamp - lag(t_stamp) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp),'1s') AS t_diff
    FROM tstmp
) AS td
WHERE t_stamp >= (SELECT t_stamp FROM td WHERE t_diff > '0ms' ORDER BY t_stamp LIMIT 1)
```

The result set from the sub query `td` contains columns `t_stamp` and `t_diff`. I'm trying to filter the result set of `td` to remove the rows before the first value of `t_diff` above `0ms`. I get the error:

```
ERROR:  relation "td" does not exist
```

am I not able to reference `td` in this part of the query (the WHERE clause)? How can I fix this?

Note: I want to avoid using a CTE due to CTE limitations in Postgres.

The result set from the sub query `td` will be like the following:

```
         t_stamp         |    t_diff
-------------------------+--------------
 2013-08-11 07:12:18.204 | 00:00:00
 2013-08-11 07:12:18.455 | 00:00:00
 2013-08-11 07:12:18.705 | 00:00:00
 2013-08-11 07:13:10.82  | 00:00:51.865
 2013-08-11 07:13:11.07  | 00:00:00
```

I want to filter this result set such that rows above the first non-zero value of t_diff are filtered out. That is, the first three rows in the above result set would be filtered out. And the enclosing query will operate on the filtered result set.

Answer (score 1):

The error was claused by your `td` alias name is only for your `from` subquery `td` can't know the alias `td` in `where`

You can try to use `cte` instead of subquery.

```
with td as (
    SELECT
        t_stamp
        , getdiffabove(t_stamp - lag(t_stamp) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp),'1s') AS t_diff
    FROM tstmp
)
SELECT t_stamp, sum(t_diff) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp) AS t_sum
FROM td
WHERE t_stamp >= (
    SELECT t_stamp 
    FROM td 
    WHERE t_diff > '0ms' 
    ORDER BY t_stamp 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

if you don't want to use `cte` you can try to use subquery nested subquery

```
SELECT t_stamp, sum(t_diff) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp) AS t_sum
FROM (
    SELECT *,SUM(CASE WHEN t_diff > '0ms' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp) cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT
            t_stamp
            ,getdiffabove(t_stamp - lag(t_stamp) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp),'1s') AS t_diff
        FROM tstmp
    ) t
) AS td
WHERE cnt > 0
```

Comment: As per the note I just added to the post I want to avoid using a CTE. Is there another way I can filter the results without using a CTE?

Comment: Ok could you provide some sample data or expect result for us? and what's you query logic?

Comment: @iamthebull I am not sure why you don't want to use `cte` but I think subquery nested subquery can solve your problem

Comment: I am having performance issues using CTEs with large tables. I'm not sure the exact issue just yet but the information in [this article](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/) may include some reasons why. With that being said your solution, while valid and correct, introduces a lot of overhead (ie. adding an additional column and aggregating the values) and I'm already dealing with large tables so performance may not be great.

Comment: Is there a way to essentially chop off the upper rows of the result set from the sub query `td`? The whole point is to reduce the size of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT t_stamp, sum(t_diff) OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp) AS t_sum
FROM (SELECT td.*,
             MIN(t_stamp) FILTER (WHERE t_diff > '0ms' OVER () as min_t_stamp
      FROM (SELECT t_stamp,
                   getdiffabove(t_stamp - lag(t_stamp) OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp), '1s') AS t_diff,
            FROM tstmp
           ) td
      ) td
WHERE t_stamp >= min_t_stamp;
```